# Is there a way to restrict the instances of a possible product type?

Tags: haskell, types

Lets assume these 2 sum types

```
data Currency =
    | GBP
    | EUR
    | DKK

data Country =
    | DE
    | AT
    | DK
    | UK
```

and the following product type

```
 type CC = (Country, Currency)
```

Now even though all these countries are part of the European Union (yeah, dear software archeologist from the year 3000 - the UK was part of the EU once ;-) ) they have different currencies (or not). So I'd like to restrict the possible values of `CC` to

```
 (DE, EUR)
 (AT, EUR)
 (UK, GBP)
 (DK, DKK)
```

and make every other combination not expressable.
Is it possible to express such a thing on the type level?
If not how would a well versed Haskeller approach this otherwise?

Comment: What would use this kind of type-level mapping? It's reflecting real-world data that isn't static, as the UK shows.

Comment: I would claim that almost no data is static. If we were to settle Mars in the non too distant future our date system and our time system won't work anymore. For the time being I feel confident implementing 24/365. And so I do with the above static table. At the end its always a judgement call if one wants to implemt a configurable module, isn't it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This may be overkill, but depending on the context you are in, you could use a GADT. This is hinging a lot on the fact your at least your currencies don't have any constructor information.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds #-}

data Currency = GBP | EUR | DKK

data Country c where
  DE :: Country EUR
  AT :: Country EUR
  UK :: Country GBP
  DK :: Country DKK
```

Or, a variant I think is probably less useful but closer to the question

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds #-}

data Currency = GBP | EUR | DKK
data Country = DE | AT | DK | UK

data CountryCurrency country currency where
  DECC :: CountryCurrency DE EUR
  ATCC :: CountryCurrency AT EUR
  UKCC :: CountryCurrency UK GBP
  DKCC :: CountryCurrency DK DKK
```

Without a use case, it is tough to say what the best approach is. :)

Comment: Your second implementation doesn't compile because there are duplicate names for `DE`, `AT`, etc.

Comment: @DavidYoung Thanks! Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

My contention is that a product type is the wrong way to represent this mapping, and that types are not a good tool for checking its consistency. (How do you make sure you've got the mapping in the type right? If the mapping changes then you need to change the type too.)

Each country has exactly one currency, and the currency is uniquely determined by the country. Sounds more like a function than a pair.

```
currency :: Country -> Currency
currency DE = EUR
currency AT = EUR
currency UK = GBP
currency DK = DKK
```

Answer (score 1):

[Edit: I had overlooked the fact that the OP was asking for a solution on the type level, for compile-time checking; my answer doesn't answer that, but could in general be a good alternative in similar situations]

I believe the idiomatic way to do this is to use [smart constructors](https://wiki.haskell.org/Smart_constructors). In a nutshell: You define your data types in a module and don't export the "dangerous" data constructor (the one that would allow "illegal" combinations); instead you export a function that only makes legal values. In your case:

```
module Money ( CountryCurrency
             , Country (..)
             , Currency (..)
             , cc
             ) where

data Currency = GBP | EUR | DKK deriving Show

data Country = DE | AT | DK | UK deriving Show

data CountryCurrency = CC Country Currency deriving Show

cc :: Country -> Currency -> CountryCurrency
cc DE EUR = CC DE EUR
cc AT EUR = CC AT EUR
cc UK GBP = CC UK GBP
cc DK DKK = CC DK DKK
cc _ _ = error "invalid country/currency combination"
```

`cc` is the smart constructor. You can then make valid combinations like this:

```
*Main> cc DE EUR
CC DE EUR

*Main> cc UK GBP
CC UK GBP
```

But you cannot make illegal ones:

```
*Main> cc UK EUR
*** Exception: invalid country/currency combination
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at ./Money.hs:18:10 in main:Money
```

Most importantly, you cannot use the data constructor `CC` directly:

```
*Main> CC UK EUR

<interactive>:26:1: error:
    Data constructor not in scope: CC :: Country -> Currency -> t
```

Comment: my aim was to have a compile time check.

Comment: @robkuz The smart constructor link has something to say about that, too. Perhaps it'll help.

Comment: I think `Country -> Currency -> Maybe CountryCurrency` would be better. partial functions are evil.